# Cypress appending port 1433 while connecting to network SQL Server which is on port 4400

Tags: sql-server, cypress

I am trying to connect to SQL Server using Cypress using "cypress-sql-server". Whenever I try to connect to the network server with "loadDBPlugin", it appends port 1433 as the suffix automatically.
I want to use port 4400 to get the information.

Code:

```
Plugins\index.js :
 
const sqlServer = require('cypress-sql-server');
const dbConfig = require('../../cypress.json');
module.exports = (on, config) => {​​​​​​​​
 
    tasks = sqlServer.loadDBPlugin(dbConfig.db);
    on('task', tasks);
 
  }​​​​​​​​
 
Cypress.json:
{​​​​​​​​
"db": {​​
        "server": "<network server>:4400",
        "port": 4400,
        "user": "<username>",
        "password": "<password>",
        "database": "<dbName>",
        "options": {​​​​​​​​​
            "enableArithAbort": true,
            "trustServerCertificate": true
        }​​​​​​​​​,
        "connectionTimeout": 150000,
        "pool": {​​​​​​​​​
            "max": 10,
            "min": 0,
            "idleTimeoutMillis": 30000
        }​​​​​​​​​
 
    }​​​​​​​​​
 
Spec file code:
let result = cy.sqlServer(query)
        cy.log(result)
 
error:
 
cy.task('sqlServer:execute') failed with the following error: > Failed to connect to <network server>:4400:1433 - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND <network server>:4400
```

Comment: Try leaving out `port` and using `<server>,4400` as the server.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Still getting the same error, cypress appends further <server>,4400:1433 while connection